# How to remove preloaded images from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, image, dom, memory, preload

I am using Javascript to preload images in a slideshow on my site so they are cached when they get requested (Note: Usually happens on the same page, no refresh. However, depending on the user behaviour, this is only true for a fraction of the images!).

I am caching the images like this:

```
function cacheImage(url) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() { // do some stuff }
}
```

Now, I am caching up to multiple hundreds of images (even gifs) on the site. My question is, wouldn't it increase the performance of my page if I remove the images after they have loaded from the DOM in order to free up memory (in my understanding, they would still be cached in a different location on the computer and served from there if requested again)? If yes, how? If no, why does this not work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no lasting reference to the `img` element that you preloaded, it will be garbage collected by Javascript so no DOM element will remain in memory.

The browser cache will have the image data.  It will be in the disk cache and, depending upon how much else is going on in the page, may also be in the memory cache.  But, the cache is automatically managed by the browser, there is no way to remove a specific item from the memory cache and, even if you could, it would not speed up the performance of your page.

One thing you could do to speed up your site in general is to only do the caching for a given image once on your site and not do it on every page.  Once it's been cached on one page, there is no particular reason to preload it again on another page on the same site.  Once it's in the disk cache from the first preload, it's plenty fast whenever it is needed again.  To keep track of what you have already cached, you may need to store some data in LocalStorage to keep track of which image was precached and when.

If you're really precaching hundreds of images, all from the same page, that's probably just too much.  The first time a user hits that page, it's going to try to initiate hundreds of individual connections to preload all those images.  While, the browser will limit how many connections may be made at once, this is still a lot to do.  I can't help but think that there must be smarter way to either pre-cache less or pre-cache only the things that are most likely to be actually used on this particular page to reduce the number down to no more than 20 or so.